# Add UDID to Application Level

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I can add UDID to my Developer Account but Can I add UDID on Application Level ? What is the significance of UDID in Dev Account ?

EDIT : I got the answer.

At the time of Ad-hoc distribution we can add 100 UDIDs of devices on which we want to test our application.

"Only Team Agents are authorized to prepare and submit applications for distribution."

Comment: Please post your own answer, instead of editing other people's.

Comment: You've tried to edit the answer by **Ishu**. We don't usually edit other people's answers to add information to them. If you have something substantial to say on this topic, you can always add your own answer.

Comment: Okay , My mistake. I thought to add more information in some answer will make it better for Any Other User who is going through it. Anyways Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Your words make sense, yet people post different answers for the purpose of voting: so that community can decide which one is better. That's why we don't put all information we can in a single big answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDID is used for making provisonig file.so when you make an app then you need to use that

UDID for creatin provisioning file so this shows significance of UDID at application level and for dev account.

And also your UDID used for generating certificates.